# php: relative path in included files

Tags: php, html, relative-path

I have an html file images.html that shows images in subdirectory "img". It uses relative path to access the images in subdir.

Everything goes wrong when in my index.php I do:

```
require_once("dir1/dir2/images.html");
```

Now the relative path is relative to my index.php, not to dir1/dir2/images.html and I can't see my images. Is there a way I can make the path relative to the **included** file images.html?

**directory structure**

```
index.php
dir1
   dir2
       images.html
       img
           flower.png
```

**index.php**

```
<?php require_once("dir1/dir2/images.html"); ?>
```

**images.html**

```
<img src="img/flower.png" />
```

Comment: PHP's internal workings do not influence the way images are loaded in the browser. Show more info: what path do your `<img>` tags have, and where are they located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an HTML problem, not a PHP.

When you access with your browser `/dir1/dir2/images.html`, the browser uses `/dir1/dir2` as base for relative path (so relative path `img/flower.png` is resolved to `/dir1/dir2/img/flower.png`). When you access `/index.php`, it uses `/` as base (so `img/flower.png` gives `/img/flower.png`, which can't be found).

You can either:

- use absolute paths for your images (eg. `/dir1/dir2/img/...`)
- use the [`base` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/HTML/Element/base) to set a new base for **all** relative paths (including links, CSS, etc) - Edit: this might not be a good idea in your case :)

Answer (score 0):

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/include.php');
```

REF : http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, **FILE** always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with PHP and the way to include files (there is no PHP in the included file). It's about path resolution by the browser.